# How do I draw graphs in a tree layout in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to draw graphs (trees), and I looking for a algorithms to layout the graph. Is there a library to do that in matlab? Otherwise, can somebody point to a good resource for that, preferably available online?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look a the function `treeviewer`

Answer (score 0):

Bioinformatics Toolbox has a nice set of tools for graph layout and display, and graph-theoretic operations, based around the biograph class.

---

Edit: As of R2015b, MATLAB includes a [suite of tools](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graph-and-network-algorithms.html) for handling and displaying graphs. Bioinformatics Toolbox is not necessary to access the suite.